# Random walk with single absorbing boundary

Tags: markov-chains

There is a random walk on a linear lattice of size $\{0,N\}$, where $0$ is the origin and a reflecting boundary and $N$ is the absorbing boundary. It moves forward or backward one step at a time with $\frac12$ probability. The number of times a state/point $(p)$ inside the lattice being visited before it gets absorbed was calculated as $2(N-p)$, $2$ times the distance between the point and $N$.
(I got this result in simulation, I don't know how to derive this mathematically.)

If I increase the step size (moving more than one step at a time) the walker can take $x+i$ or $x-i$ with $\frac{1}{2}$ probability, where $i=1,2,3,\dots,k$. That is if k is 2, then the walker can either take 1 step or 2 step forward/backward with equal probability ($\frac{1}{2k}$).

However, if the walker goes beyond the boundary [$<0$ or $>N$], then it'll be reflected back as follows,
$$ \mbox{new  x} = \begin{Bmatrix}
0+(0-x) & \mbox{if} \ x < 0\\ 
N-(x-N) & \mbox{if} \ x > N
\end{Bmatrix} $$

How to derive the number of visits [i.e. $2(N-p)$] mathematically for single step random walk? And how the increase in step size $k$ will affect the same?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The number of times or expected number of times?

Comment: its expected number of times only.

Comment: I'm not quite clear on what you mean by *multistep*, but in your new chain are the transition probabilities 1/4, 1/2, 1/4 to go to  x-1,x,x+1 respectively, starting at x, for 0<x<N?

Comment: the transition probability is still 1/2 only, but now the walker will go to "x+k" th position with 1/2 probability and "x-k"th position with 1/2 probability from x. Here k is greater than 1.

Comment: @dexter What if he starts at $0<x<k$?

Comment: @Byron Schmuland: it is still 2(N-p) for all p's[p > x, x is the starting point]. I got this result from simulation.

Comment: @dexter No, I am asking about the transition probabilities. If you start at $x=1$ when $k=2$, with probability 1/2 you move to $-1$? If $k$ is larger, do you allow more and more boundary points at both ends? You ought to clarify your model more precisely. That way you will get more helpful answers on this site.

Comment: sorry about that.When a walker goes beyond my boundary (< 0 or > N) then it will be reflected back into the lattice as, 
if x < 0, new_x=0+(0-x) & if x > N, new_x = N-(x-N);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define 
$$e(x)=\mathbb{E}_x(\mbox{number of visits to state }p).$$
Then $e$ is the unique function that satisfies 
$e(N)=0$, $e(x)=(Pe)(x)$ for $x\neq p$, and 
$e(p)=1+(Pe)(p)$. That is, the function
 $e$ is harmonic at all points except $p$, where it is 1-harmonic. 
Here $$(Pe)(x)=\mathbb{E}_x(e(X_1))=\sum_y p_{xy} e(y).$$

The function $e$ can always
 be calculated, in principle, using linear algebra.

The case $k=1$ is particularly easy, since in this 
context "harmonic" means linear, and the chain is continuous, 
in the sense that it can't jump over states. 
In particular, the value of $e(x)$ is constant 
for all $x\leq p$.

On the right, $e$ is a straight line function from
$e(p)$ at $p$ to zero at $N$, that is, it is of the 
form $e(x)=c(N-x)$ for $p\leq x\leq N$.  Now, the
 1-harmonicity of $e$ at $p$ gives 
$$e(p)= 1+ (1/2)e(p-1)+(1/2)e(p+1),$$
so that $e(p)=2+e(p+1)$ and so $c(N-p)=2+c(N-(p+1))$. 
Solving gives $c=2$ and we conclude that 
$$e(x)=2(N-(x\vee p))\mbox{ for } 0\leq x\leq N.$$

In general, with multisteps and your boundary conditions 
we lose the nice, explicit formula.

---

The function $e$ is the solution of
$(I-\widetilde P)e=\delta_p$ where $I$ is the identity matrix,
$\widetilde P$ is $P$ modified by replacing the 1 in the bottom right hand corner by a 0,
and $\delta_p$ is the vector with a one in position $p$, and zero elsewhere.

Here is a worked out example when $N=5$, $p=1$, and $k=2$. In this case,
the transition matrix for the Markov chain is 
$$P=\pmatrix{0& 1/2& 1/2& 0& 0& 0\\ 
            1/4& 1/4& 1/4& 1/4& 0& 0\\
            1/4& 1/4& 0& 1/4& 1/4& 0\\  
            0& 1/4& 1/4& 0& 1/4& 1/4\\ 
            0& 0& 1/4& 1/4& 1/4& 1/4\\
            0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 1}$$

The solution to  $(I-\widetilde P)e= \delta_p$ is
$$e=\left[{200\over 55},{236\over 55},{164\over 55},{124\over 55},{96\over 55},0\right]
= [3.636, 4.291, 2.982, 2.255, 1.745, 0.000].$$

$\hskip2in$ [image]

The graph above compares the expected number of visits to state 1 under the single step ($k=1$) and the multistep ($k=2$) schemes. The multistep walk diffuses much faster and is absorbed sooner, hence making fewer visits to state 1.

Comment: Thankyou so much, thats exactly what I want.Can you explain me how you did that?(I have changed the details of the problem.)

Comment: @dexter My solution is based on a misunderstanding of your rules. I will have to redo it completely. I will try to find time tonight or tomorrow.

Comment: that is amazing... thanks a lot.. but i don't understand how you got $e(p) = 2 + e(p+1)$. Am sorry if its a lame question.(I'm a biologist)

Comment: Start with $e(p)= 1+ (1/2)e(p-1)+(1/2)e(p+1)$ and use the fact that $e(p-1)=e(p)$. That means $e(p)= 1+ (1/2)e(p)+(1/2)e(p+1)$. Now subtract $(1/2)e(p)$ from both sides and multiply the whole works by 2.

Comment: is $ e(p-1) = e(p)$ because of the 1-horminicity?

Comment: No, because $e(x)$ is the same for all $0\leq x\leq p$.

Comment: ok i just grouped all the $ p's(p, p-1,p+1)$ now i understood.Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: sorry to bother you.Could you please suggest me some method to solve this for multistep? I tried with $e(p)=1+\sum_{i=1}^{k}{(1/2k)e(p+1)}+\sum_{i=1}^{k}{(1/2k)e(p-1)} $ but the ans is totally different from my simulation result.

Comment: thank you,thankyou so much.. Thats a very timely help.

Comment: sorry to bug you again, could you please tell me how can you say e(x) is a constant for all $ x \geq p$ ?

Comment: May I suggest that you post this as a separate problem? In case I have no time to answer someone else may help out.

Comment: Sure i'll do that. Thanks